# Web3.py uniswap is status :0 with swapExactTokensForTokens

Tags: python, swap, web3py, uniswap

I've been testing swap function with python web3.py on python3.
But it is having only status : 0 on receipt.
I have tried to use amountin and amountout from getAmountsOut function but it is same.

````
approve = tokenContract.functions.approve(ROUTER_ADDRESS, am).buildTransaction({
        'from': SENDER_ADDRESS,
        # 'gas' : 250000,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('40', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SENDER_ADDRESS),
        # 'value':0
    })

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
        approve, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)
    tx_token = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

    print("approved : " + web3.toHex(tx_token))

    receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(
        tx_token, timeout=30000, poll_latency=0.1)
    
    amount = routerContract.functions.getAmountsOut(am,[TOKEN_ADDRESS,TARGET_ADDRESS]).call()
    print(amount)

    swap = routerContract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        web3.toWei('0.0001', 'ether'),#am,
        0,
        [TOKEN_ADDRESS,TARGET_ADDRESS],
        SENDER_ADDRESS,
        (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
    ).buildTransaction({
        'from': SENDER_ADDRESS,
        # 'value': web3.toWei('0.0001','ether'),
        'gas': 250000 ,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('60', 'gwei'),
        'nonce':  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SENDER_ADDRESS),
    })

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
        swap, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)
    tx_swap = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

    print(web3.toHex(tx_swap))

    print("Wait...")
    time.sleep(5)
    receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(
        tx_swap, timeout=30000, poll_latency=0.1)
    print(receipt)```

This is transaction link from my swap testing : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x995ca7515fa7e2afe429cf248d772121aaeb456088b2fd674dd30b5816a2a33b
Thanks.
````

Comment: [You can find multiple working examples of Uniswap swap function tests in Python and Web3.py here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/106408/620).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is the value of `am` that you approve in your code, but from what I can see from your activity on Etherscan, you:

1. approved 414998989012 wei of POM
2. try to swap 100000000000000 wei of POM

You would need your allowance to be greater than the amount you swap.

Comment: BTW, no need to approve many times. Just one with a value > 100000000000000 is ok for this swap. For your tests, you can even approve up to the max which is 2**256 - 1. Then set it back to 0 after it.

Comment: Also, you might want to test on a  testnet to avoid paying actual trx fees ... For ex Görli or a local fork using Ganache

Comment: And lastly, in this context, Etherscan showing a 'TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' error is a good indicator of an allowance issue.